# iMacros Infinite Loop

Tags: infinite-loop, imacros

I am trying to create an infinite loop to refresh a slideshow using imacros

Below is my code, but it doesn't loop infinitely.
Any suggestions?

VERSION BUILD=1011 RECORDER=CR

URL GOTO=https://show.zoho.com/show/present/cg855a998a52d359b4baead030f335d3b95be/slide/876E3E34-F0D7-42BC-8A91-CC472F152141

WAIT SECONDS=1000

REFRESH

URL GOTO=[https://show.zoho.com/show/present/cg855a998a52d359b4baead030f335d3b95be/slide/876E3E34-F0D7-42BC-8A91-CC472F152141]

Answer (score 0):

you have to click on play(loop) and insert your desider max loop. you can put a high number to simulate an infinite one.

[image]